# Do I have to run cordova emulate ios everytime

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I'm new to cordova and I have an app running in the ios simulator. My question is, do I have to run:

```
cordova emulate ios
```

every time I edit one of my files?

Also, I have to go to safari > develop > simulator every time. It would be nice if the developer tools would just stay up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run your app in a simulator or on a real device you have to go through the native build process every time - yes, thats because you want to run a native app (which needs to be compiled) containing your js part. But for development you could use something like [cordova-plugin-browsersync](https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync) which should speed up your development quite a bit.